# Ajax not working well until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a page called pos, on this page I submit a form with ajax and then I get result without refreshing the page.

on the left side of the page I have a table that shows the products I have added after submitting the form.
on the same page I have a javascript code that changes the price of items in real time when the quantities are changed and it automatically changes the total price with help of ajax.

unfortunately after submitting a form and table pops up without refreshing the page with the help of AJAX the javascript code to help dynamically change the product quantity doesn't work as expected till I refresh the page.

```html
//pos page code below
<?php 
  $userAccess = $_SESSION['accessLevel'] ;
  $userIDSession = $_SESSION['user_uniq_id'] ;

  $getCart="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user = '$userIDSession'";
  $connectget = mysqli_query($conn,$getCart);
  $fetchGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connectget);


?>
<div class="row row-sm" id="">
  <div class="col-xl-5 col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Point Of Sale</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" id="pos" novalidate="novalidate">
          <label for="product_code">Product Code:</label>
          <input type="text" id="product_code" class="form-control" name="product_code">
          <input type="text" id="accessLevel" class="form-control" name="accessLevel" value="<?=$userAccess?>" hidden="">
          <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" name="user" value="<?=$userIDSession?>" hidden="">
          <button class="btn btn-success mt-2 posAdd" type="submit" name="posAdd">Submit</button>
          <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="error_message" style="display: none;"></div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="error_message1" style="display: none;"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-7 col-md-12" id="showCartInfo">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="col">
            <h3 class="card-title">Cart</h3>
          </div>
          <?php
            if ($connectget && mysqli_num_rows($connectget) > 0) {
          ?>
            <div class="col">
              <h3 class="card-title text-danger" onclick="cancelPurchase('<?=$userIDSession?>')" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fe fe-x-circle"></i> Clear Cart</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <h3 class="card-title text-success"><i class="fe fe-check-circle"></i> <a href="./checkout&c=<?=$userIDSession?>" style="text-decoration:none;">Check Out </a></h3>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" id="cart_table">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Item Price</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <form method="POST" id="posCalc">
            <input type="text" name="user" value="<?=$userIDSession?>" hidden="" id="user">
            <tbody>
              <?php
              $query="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user = '$userIDSession'";
              $result = $conn->query($query);
              while($fetchResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $productName=$fetchResult['productName'];
                $itemPrice=$fetchResult['itemPrice'];
                $price=$fetchResult['price'];
                $qty=$fetchResult['qty'];
                $itemCode=$fetchResult['productCode'];
              ?>
                <tr>
                  <input type="text" name="itemCode[]" value="<?=$itemCode?>" hidden="">
                  <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?=$productName?>" readonly="" id=""> </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" readonly="" value="<?=$itemPrice?>" id="itemprice<?=$itemCode?>" onchange="calculatePrice('<?=$itemCode?>')"></td>
                  <td><input type="number" name="qty[]" class="form-control" value="<?=$qty?>" min="1" id="qty<?=$itemCode?>" onkeyup="calculatePrice('<?=$itemCode?>')"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" readonly="" value="<?=$price?>" id="price<?=$itemCode?>">
                  </td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="fe fe-trash btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteCartItem('<?=$itemCode?>','<?=$userIDSession?>')"></button></td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
            </tbody>

          </form>
        </table>
        <div class="text-right">
          <strong>Total Price:</strong>

          <span id="total_price" class="alert alert-info">GHC 0.00</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  // Script to change price in real time
  function calculatePrice(id) {
    var item = parseFloat($('#itemprice' + id).val()) || 0;
    var qty = parseFloat($('#qty' + id).val()) || 0;
    console.log(item);
    console.log(qty);
    var price = qty * item;
    $('#price' + id).val(price.toFixed(2));
    var posDataCalc = $("#posCalc").serialize();
    updateTotalPrice(posDataCalc);
    console.log(posDataCalc);
  }

  $("#posCalc :input").change(function() {
    var posDataCalc = $("#posCalc").serialize();
    updateTotalPrice(posDataCalc);
  });

  function updateTotalPrice(posDataCalc) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?=$pageUrl?>/handlers/calculatePrice.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: posDataCalc,
      success: function(resultPrice) {
        $('#total_price').text(resultPrice);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

```js
//This code processes the form to insert data code
$("#pos").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var posData = new FormData(this);
  prcFormpos(posData);
});
// Process Form
function prcFormpos(posData) {
  var product_code = $("#product_code").val();
  if (product_code !== "") {
    $(".posAdd").attr("disabled", "");
    $("#pos").fadeTo("slow", 0.5).css("pointer-events", "none");

    $.ajax({
      url: "./handlers/check_product_code.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: posData,
      success: function(dataResultPos) {
        if (parseInt(dataResultPos) === 2) {
          $(".posAdd").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#pos").fadeTo("slow", 1).css("pointer-events", "auto");
          $('#error_message1').hide('');
          $('#error_message1').text('');
          $('#error_message').show('');
          $('#error_message').text('Invalid Product Code ');
        } else if (parseInt(dataResultPos) === 3) {
          $(".posAdd").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#pos").fadeTo("slow", 1).css("pointer-events", "auto");
          swal("Error", "An Error Occurred Kindly Refresh The Page", "error");
          console.log(dataResultPos);
        } else {
          $(".posAdd").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#pos").fadeTo("slow", 1).css("pointer-events", "auto");
          $("#showCartInfo").html(dataResultPos);
          $("#pos")[0].reset();
          $('#error_message').hide('');
          $('#error_message').text('');
          $('#error_message1').hide('');
          $('#error_message1').text('');
        }
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
    });
  } else {
    $(".posAdd").removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#error_message').hide('');
    $('#error_message').text('');
    $('#error_message1').show('');
    $('#error_message1').text('Product Code Empty ');
  }
}



function cancelPurchase(userIDSession) {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You want to cancel the order?",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
  }).then((willTrigger) => {
    if (willTrigger) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "./handlers/cancelOrder.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          userIDSession: userIDSession,
        },
        success: function(data1) {
          console.log(data1);
          swal("Success", "Order Cancelled Successfully", "success");
          $("#showCartInfo").html(data1);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
          swal("Error", "Failed to cancel the order", "error");
        },
      });
      swal({
        title: "Great!",
        text: "Cancelling Order From Cart",
        icon: "info",
        buttons: false,
      });
    } else {
      swal("Great", "Order Not Cancelled", "success");
    }
  });
}

function deleteCartItem(productCode, userIDSession) {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You want to delete the item?",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
  }).then((willTrigger) => {
    if (willTrigger) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "./handlers/deleteCartItem.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          userIDSession: userIDSession,
          productCode: productCode,
        },
        success: function(data1) {
          console.log(data1);
          swal("Success", "Item Deleted Successfully", "success");
          $("#showCartInfo").html(data1);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
          swal("Error", "Failed to delete the item", "error");
        },
      });
      swal({
        title: "Great!",
        text: "Deleting Item From Cart",
        icon: "info",
        buttons: false,
      });
    } else {
      swal("Great", "Item Not Deleted", "success");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<?php
include '../connect.php'; 

if (isset($_POST['product_code'])) {
  $productCode = $_POST['product_code'];
  $accessLevel = $_POST['accessLevel'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];

  if ($accessLevel >= 3) {
    // admin
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pCode='$productCode'";
    $powerQuery1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    $fetchQuery = mysqli_fetch_assoc($powerQuery1);

    if ($powerQuery1 && mysqli_num_rows($powerQuery1) > 0) {
      $productName = $fetchQuery['pName'];
      $productShop = $fetchQuery['pShop'];
      $productPrice = $fetchQuery['pSellPrice'];
      $productID = $fetchQuery['pID'];

      $query2 = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE productCode='$productCode' AND user='$user'";
      $powerQuery2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
      $fetchQuery2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($powerQuery2);

      if ($powerQuery2 && mysqli_num_rows($powerQuery2) == 0) {
       $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `cart`(`productCode`, `productName`, `qty`, `itemPrice`, `price`, `user`,`productID`) VALUES ('$productCode','$productName',1,'$productPrice','$productPrice','$user','$productID')";
        $powerInsert = mysqli_query($conn, $insertQuery);
        if ($powerInsert==true) {
            $getCart="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user = '$user'";
            $connectget = mysqli_query($conn,$getCart);
            $fetchGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connectget);
        ?>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="col">
          <h3 class="card-title">Cart</h3>
        </div>
        <?php
                if ($connectget && mysqli_num_rows($connectget) > 0) {
              ?>
          <div class="col">
            <h3 class="card-title text-danger" onclick="cancelPurchase('<?=$user?>')" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fe fe-x-circle"></i> Clear Cart</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <h3 class="card-title text-success"><i class="fe fe-check-circle"></i> <a href="./checkout&c=<?=$user?>" style="text-decoration:none;">Check Out </a></h3>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body" id="cart_table">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <form method="POST" id="posCalc">
          <input type="text" name="user" value="<?=$user?>" hidden="" id="user">
          <tbody>
            <?php
                  $query="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user = '$user'";
                  $result = $conn->query($query);
                  while($fetchResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $productName=$fetchResult['productName'];
                    $itemPrice=$fetchResult['itemPrice'];
                    $price=$fetchResult['price'];
                    $qty=$fetchResult['qty'];
                    $itemCode=$fetchResult['productCode'];
                  ?>
              <tr>
                <input type="text" name="itemCode[]" value="<?=$itemCode?>" hidden="">
                <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?=$productName?>" readonly="" id=""> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" readonly="" value="<?=$itemPrice?>" id="itemprice<?=$itemCode?>" onchange="calculatePrice('<?=$itemCode?>')"></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="qty[]" class="form-control" value="<?=$qty?>" min="1" id="qty<?=$itemCode?>" onkeyup="calculatePrice('<?=$itemCode?>')"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" readonly="" value="<?=$price?>" id="price<?=$itemCode?>">
                </td>
                <td><button type="button" class="fe fe-trash btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteCartItem('<?=$itemCode?>','<?=$user?>')"></button></td>
              </tr>
              <?php }?>
          </tbody>

        </form>
      </table>
      <div class="text-right">
        <strong>Total Price:</strong>
        <span id="total_price" class="alert alert-info">GHC 0.00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  <script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/js/ajax-trigger.js"></script> -->

  <?php }else{echo 3;} 
      } else if ($powerQuery2 && mysqli_num_rows($powerQuery2) > 0) {
        // fetch details about the product you are about to update
        $queryItem="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE productCode = '$productCode' AND user='$user'";
        $powerqueryItem = mysqli_query($conn,$queryItem);
        $getItem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($powerqueryItem);
        $currentqty = $getItem['qty'];
        $newqty = $currentqty + 1;
        $newPrice = $newqty * $productPrice;

        $updateQuery = "UPDATE cart SET qty='$newqty',price='$newPrice' WHERE productCode='$productCode' AND user = '$user'";
        $connectQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$updateQuery);
        if ($connectQuery==true) {
          $getCart="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user = '$user'";
          $connectget = mysqli_query($conn,$getCart);
          $fetchGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connectget);
        ?>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="col">
          <h3 class="card-title">Cart</h3>
        </div>
        <?php
                if ($connectget && mysqli_num_rows($connectget) > 0) {
              ?>
          <div class="col">
            <h3 class="card-title text-danger" onclick="cancelPurchase('<?=$user?>')" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fe fe-x-circle"></i> Clear Cart</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <h3 class="card-title text-success"><i class="fe fe-check-circle"></i> <a href="./checkout&c=<?=$user?>" style="text-decoration:none;">Check Out </a></h3>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body" id="cart_table">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <form method="POST" id="posCalc">
          <input type="text" name="user" value="<?=$user?>" hidden="" id="user">
          <tbody>
            <?php
                  $query="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user = '$user'";
                  $result = $conn->query($query);
                  while($fetchResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $productName=$fetchResult['productName'];
                    $itemPrice=$fetchResult['itemPrice'];
                    $price=$fetchResult['price'];
                    $qty=$fetchResult['qty'];
                    $itemCode=$fetchResult['productCode'];
                  ?>
              <tr>
                <input type="text" name="itemCode[]" value="<?=$itemCode?>" hidden="">
                <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?=$productName?>" readonly="" id=""> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" readonly="" value="<?=$itemPrice?>" id="itemprice<?=$itemCode?>" onchange="calculatePrice('<?=$itemCode?>')"></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="qty[]" class="form-control" value="<?=$qty?>" min="1" id="qty<?=$itemCode?>" onkeyup="calculatePrice('<?=$itemCode?>')"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" readonly="" value="<?=$price?>" id="price<?=$itemCode?>">
                </td>
                <td><button type="button" class="fe fe-trash btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteCartItem('<?=$itemCode?>','<?=$user?>')"></button></td>
              </tr>
              <?php }?>
          </tbody>

        </form>
      </table>
      <div class="text-right">
        <strong>Total Price:</strong>
        <?php 
              $sumQuery = "SELECT SUM(price) AS totalPrice FROM cart WHERE user = '$user'";
              $powerSum = mysqli_query($conn,$sumQuery);
              $fetchTotal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($powerSum);
              $totalPrice = $fetchTotal['totalPrice'];

              ?>
        <span id="total_price"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php }  
      }


    } else {
      echo 2;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the codes, but could you rework your text above it a bit, so it become a bit more understandable? Or is it me?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware basically javascript on the pos page doesn't work after I insert a new data until I refresh the page

Comment: You probably want to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). As in `$('#posCalc').on('change', ':input', function () { /* change handler */ })`.